# Disable form redirect

Tags: 6, forms

I want to disable the form redirect.

```
$form['#redirect'] = FALSE;
$form_state['#redirect'] = FALSE;
```

Neither of those works.

How can I turn off form redirect? I want to see the output of `$form_values`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want see the $form_values array, I suggest you to install Devel and use the function dsm or even you can use the drupal_set_message with print_r.

Comment: You can still use `drupal_set_message + print_r($vars, true)` it doesn't require you install something else.

Comment: The site is done in such horrible way, that drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($form_state,1).'</pre>'), gives me empty $message.

Comment: Well, if you can, do a `echo <pre>'. print_r($form_state, 1); die();`

Comment: Well it seems that validate and submit handler doen't even invoke. What a mess :(

Answer (score 0):

for Drupal 7
a redirect wont occur if any of these variables are set and returns false when checked with empty()
$form_state['programmed'] , $form_state['rebuild'] or $form_state['no_redirect']

you can try by setting in hook_form_alter,

```
$form_state['no_redirect'] = TRUE
```

Comment: Ok.. is this documented anywhere on drupal.org?